# Access Android string resources from code

Tags: android, string

In xml layouts I'm using:

```
android:text="@android:string/ok"
```

How can I get that resource from java code?
This doesn't work:

```
resources.getString(R.android.string.ok);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
resources.getString(android.R.string.ok);
```